# Best Open Source Asp.net (ajaxable) Forum

Tags: asp.net, unicode, asp.net-ajax, custom-controls, forum

I'm looking for a good Forum to include in my application.

I find Community Server toouseful but it is notopen source, any Sugesstion will appriciate.

this forum should have an API to extend. and support Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know of 2 open source forums for ASP.NET

http://www.yetanotherforum.net/

http://punbb.informer.com/wiki/punbb.net/start

The first one, Yet Another Forum is probably your best bet. It supports Unicode (UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

free [ASP.Net forum software](http://www.insecla.com/forum/) by insecla.com

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:http://umbraco.org/